# Filling a profile field on User Meta Update

Tags: php, wordpress, function

To export users who changed their profile data (WP All Export Pro), I need to fill the profile field "description" with text at the moment, the frontend-user clicks save to update their profile.

The user fields are a bunch of Meta fields (Custom Checkout fields) that are used on the account page.

```
function my_profile_update( $user_id ) {    
    
    if (!defined( 'WP_IMPORTING' )  ) { 
        
        if (!is_checkout()) {
                
            $user_geaendert = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'description', true);

            if (strpos($user_geaendert, 'Export') !== false) {
                    
                
            } else {
                
                update_user_meta( $user_id, 'description', 'seit letztem Export geändert ' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));          

                $to = 'test@test.de';
                //$to = 'test2@test.com, test@test.de';
                $subject = "Benutzerdaten geändert";
                $message =  'Benutzer mit der ID '.$user_id.' hat seine Daten geändert. https://link.de/wp-admin/user-edit.php?user_id='.$user_id;      

                wp_mail($to, $subject, $message);
            
            }
        } 
    } else {

        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'description', '');
        
    } 
}
add_action( 'profile_update', 'my_profile_update' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'my_profile_update' );
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'my_profile_update' );
//add_action( 'update_user_meta', 'my_profile_update' );
```

This code is working correctly when you update the fields in the backend, because it's inside of the profile and you update the profile, it is not working when you update the user on the frontend, because there you'll only have the User Meta.

The following is my try at this solution, but it doesn't work:

```
function UpdateAddAction() {
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' and $post->ID == 9) {
        //add_action( 'update_user_meta', 'my_profile_update' );
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'description', 'seit letztem Export geändert ' . date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
    }
}

UpdateAddAction();
```

Do you have an idea where I'm wrong?